# Jenkins jobs for spring boot application with Integration testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jenkins

The following is my scenario.

I have my application which is built on Spring boot with embedded tomcat server. In my application, I have unit tests as well as integration tests.

First I want to build my application as a maven package (jar) which will cover all the unit tests and then the next step is to run the jar file as spring boot application ((java -jar myapplication.jar) which will start the tomcat server. As a final step, I want to run my integration tests on top of the running spring boot application.

To achieve this in Jenkins what is the best solutions.

1. Is it possible to have a single Jenkins job and achieve the above scenario? (like in post-build steps to run the generated jar as an application using the command and run the integration test on it)
2. Else will create 3 jobs in Jenkins ( one for maven package, the second one for deploying the generated jar file and run the application and third one is for running the integration tests on top of the running application.

Please suggest the best possible solution.

Thanks in advance.

Bala.

Answer (score 0):

This should help (if you're using maven to build the project).
The general idea is to use your build tool than can manage the whole process itself within one Jenkins job.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>pre-integration-test</id>
         <goals>
            <goal>start</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
         <id>post-integration-test</id>
         <goals>
            <goal>stop</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: for a 'live' example, please refer to one of my old projects here https://github.com/tkachenkoas/eyfo-falafel. There's also a readme -> check out the build configuration for 'eyfo-backend' module. The IT's run exactly the way you want

Comment: Thanks. I tried this way and its working. When it is so simple this way, i am wondering why many are setting up either multiple jobs or doing complex things in post build steps. Atleast thats what I inferred by referring to articles on the internet. Is the option that you suggested is available from some specific maven version?

Comment: it's related to spring-boot-maven-plugin, not maven directly.

actually, even without spring boot it's possible with embedded tomcat plugin.